# Using bind mount in Docker (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu

I am really new to Linux and Docker, and i want to not rebuild docker image after every change of my code. I read, that you can use bind mount, but i can't understand it's syntax and usage. My Python files with Dockerfile is located at /etc/python-docker

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Would an ordinary, non-Docker, Python virtual environment better meet your needs?  That will still have an isolated set of Python packages, but it's actually using your normal host filesystem and you don't need tricks to get to see the files you're actively working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mount your python files inside the container with the `-v` [flag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volume--v---read-only).

`docker run -v /etc/python-docker:/path/inside/the/container image-name`

Comment: Thank you, with specific example i mainly understood syntax. This is what i needed so much